# Fitnesse: is it possible to disable Test and Suite buttons?

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I am running Fitnesse on several dispathers and then copy Fitnesse history and logs from all dispatchers to a separate machine. Some other project members need access to test results on this machine but I don't want them to be able to click Test or Suite there. Is it somehow possible to disable Test and Suite buttons?

I would be glad for any options: either somehow configure it in Fitnesse, or get a patched fitnesse.jar, or any other options.

On the main Fitnesse site (http://fitnesse.org/StayInformed), there is the following note: "Note, the Test and Suite buttons on this site have been disabled because search engines tend to invoke them and put my server under stress. This site is actually created with FitNesse.". So I need something like that, if possible.

Is it possible? Not sure I can find a corresponding place in source code to patch and re-build it. My hope is whether someone already did it or find it easy to help. I raised an issue in GitHub where Fitnesse source code is located but I didn't get any feedback yet.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible, that is indeed what is done for fitnesse.org.
I'm not 100% sure how its done but I suspect it is done by disabling 'responders', see http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.AdministeringFitNesse.ConfigurationFile.

In that page a description is given to disable creating new pages:

```
Responders=addChild:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,new:org.fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder
```

You can probably also use this to disable `SuiteResponder` and `TestResponder`, by using:

```
Responders=suite:fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder,test:org.fitnesse.responders.DisabledResponder
```

The full list of responders is in [fitnesse.responders.ResponderFactory](https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse/blob/master/src/fitnesse/responders/ResponderFactory.java)

*On a side note*: why do need a full FitNesse installation to show test results? I recommend you look into generating tests results in html format, and just publish that html somewhere. I usually use the [jUnit runner](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.RunningFromJunit) to run the tests on a build server (it also creates html output) and then publish the html files generated as build artefact which people can open/view.

Sample, from FitNesse project, generating html in `build/fitnesse-results`:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(FitNesseRunner.class)
@FitNesseRunner.Suite("FitNesse.SuiteAcceptanceTests.SuiteSlimTests.TestScriptTable")
@FitNesseRunner.FitnesseDir(".")
@FitNesseRunner.OutputDir("./build/fitnesse-results")
public class FitNesseRunnerTest {
}
```